Кратчайший путь (граф в mssql)
Пытаюсь разобраться в графах в MSSQL.
Выполняю запросы по очереди из
learn.microsoft.com/
Из раздела https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-sample?view=sql-server-ver16 всё выполнилось без проблем. Но когда пытаюсь выполнить запросы из этого раздела https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-shortest-path?view=sql-server-ver16#shortest-path , например:
SELECT PersonName, Friends
FROM (
    SELECT
        Person1.name AS PersonName,
        STRING_AGG(Person2.name, '->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS Friends,
        LAST_VALUE(Person2.name) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS LastNode
    FROM
        Person AS Person1,
        friendOf FOR PATH AS fo,
        Person FOR PATH  AS Person2
    WHERE MATCH(SHORTEST_PATH(Person1(-(fo)->Person2)+))
    AND Person1.name = 'Jacob'
) AS Q
WHERE Q.LastNode = 'Alice' 

Выдаёт ошибку Incorrect syntax near 'GRAPH'
Что я не так делаю?

В показанном коде нет первой строки.

@AlexanderPetrov поправил, спасибо

Когда-то довольно давно я тоже изучал возможности Sql Server по работе с графами, повторил все примеры кода и у меня всё работало. Так что могу лишь посоветовать стандартные приёмы: протереть фары, попинать колёса... Ну то-есть перезагрузиться, обновиться и т. п.
